# Object of type Asset is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-asset-inventory

I am using GCP's Python client APIs for listing cloud assets. I need to move that output to a CSV file. But I can't because it is showing

> TypeError: Object of type Asset is not JSON serializable

My code

```
response = client.list_assets(
  request={
    "parent": project_resource,
    "read_time": None,
    "asset_types": ["compute.googleapis.com/Instance"],
    "content_type": asset_v1.ContentType.RESOURCE,
    "page_size": 50,
  }
)

for asset in response:
   print(asset)
df = json_normalize(asset)
df.to_csv('list.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')`
```

My output

```
TypeError: Object of type Asset is not JSON serializable
```

Do I need to use any other library files to convert to CSV?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the output of ```print(asset)```

Comment: Here is my output of the old case (Note: i have highlighted like " ****** " are project name, project id....its sensitive name that's y  i blurred.
`name: "//compute.googleapis.com/projects/********/zones/us-central1-c/instances/*****"
asset_type: "compute.googleapis.com/Instance"
resource {
  version: "v1"
  discovery_document_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/compute/v1/rest"
  discovery_name: "Instance"
  parent: "//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/********"
  data {
    fields {
      key: "allocationAffinity"
      value {
   struct_value {......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `Asset` is a protocol buffer message and (these classes are) not JSON serializable.

> **NOTE** Confirmed that [`Asset`](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/Asset) is a protocol buffer. The method uses gRPC Transcoding, see [`assets.list`](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/assets/list)

<strike>You should (!) be able to use `MessageToJSON` in [google.protobuf.json_format](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html) to convert the protobuf message into JSON that you can then convert to CSV. The module also includes `MessageToDict` which may (!?) be preferable in this case.</strike>

###### Update

Apparently (!) Google has changed its Protobuf support with API Client Libraries and uses [Proto Plus for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/proto-plus-python). I did not know this until your question. The solution is now (!):

```py
for asset in resp:
    j = asset_v1.Asset.to_json(asset)
```

And, IIUC, because you need to `to_json` the protocol buffer messages, you will need to iterate over `resp`, `to_json` each (!?) `asset` and then reassemble them before converting to CSV.

> **NOTE** Your code appears (!?) to create each `Asset` in the response as a separate CSV file (`list.csv`) when, I suspect you really want to serialize the response's [`assets`](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/assets/list) property (list of `Asset`) instead.

Comment: Hii @DazWilkin as u said `j = asset_v1.Asset.to_json(asset)` is working perfectly. now the thing is that for empty resoures it is not printing any result, not even empty string.
For eg: `"asset_types": ['storage.googleapis.com/Bucket',
                        'container.googleapis.com/Cluster'],`
Only for cluster it is printing, if there is no resourses in bucket, its not printing any thing not even "None",'empty'......
The problem is, i need to get intimated  by printing "No resourse found" if there is nothing in bucket. How can I achive that can u help it out?

Comment: This is really a different question. The documentation for `assets.list`, the [Response](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/assets/list#response-body) should (!) include `readTime`, `assets` and `nextPageToken`. The SDK doc explains that we really get a [`ListAssetsPager`]((https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudasset/latest/asset_v1/asset_service.html?highlight=list_assets#google.cloud.asset_v1.services.asset_service.pagers.ListAssetsPager)) pager from the method.

Comment: It is a wrapper over [`ListAssetResponse`](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudasset/latest/asset_v1/types.html#google.cloud.asset_v1.types.ListAssetsResponse) so you can actually `if len(resp.assets)==0 ...`